# reshape the elements of array based on the custom indexes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have array `A=[1,2,3,4,5]` we know that the indexes are `[0,1,2,3,4]` now I want to reshape the array based on `my_ind = [4,0,2,3,1]`, what would be the fastest way to do it?
the reshape is basically (`A[index]` as if we are in python) so that I have `B=[5,1,3,4,2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a for loop and loop through your array. There is no function for that.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

A = array.from(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5)
my_ind = array.from(4, 0, 2, 3, 1)

len_A = array.size(A)

B = array.new_int(len_A)

for i=0 to len_A-1
    val = array.get(A, array.get(my_ind, i))
    array.set(B, i, val)

var testTable = table.new( position.top_right, len_A + 1, 4, color.yellow, border_color=color.black, border_width=1)

if barstate.islast
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 0, "Array")
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 1, "my_ind")
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 2, "A")
    table.cell(testTable, 0, 3, "B")

    row = 0
    col = 1

    for i=0 to len_A-1
        val_ind = array.get(my_ind, i)
        val_A = array.get(A, i)
        val_B = array.get(B, i)

        table.cell(testTable, col, row, str.tostring(i))
        table.cell(testTable, col, row+1, str.tostring(val_ind))
        table.cell(testTable, col, row+2, str.tostring(val_A))
        table.cell(testTable, col, row+3, str.tostring(val_B))
        col := col + 1
```

[image]